# Can the Microsoft Edge WebView2 control preload the page before displaying it?

Tags: wpf, controls, preload, webview2

I am using the **Microsoft Edge WebView2** control in my **WPF** application. My application has a separate tab with a browser element that loads a specific resource.

The **WebView2** is created when the application starts:

```csharp
string userDataFolderPath = GetApplicationDataFolder();
userDataFolderPath = Path.Combine(userDataFolderPath, typeof(EOKModule).Namespace);

CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions opt = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions
{
    Language = "ru-RU"
};

CoreWebView2Environment env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, userDataFolderPath, opt);
await WebView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);

WebView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(url);
```

However, the browser does not load the page until the user opens that tab. Is there a way to **preload** the page in the browser **before displaying** it? Perhaps there is a similar setting as in the standard Microsoft Edge browser (https://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-preload-new-tab-page-on-edge)?

Comment: Is the `WebView2` created when you open the app or how do you create the tab with the `WebView`?

Comment: The content of a tab may not be instantiated until the user opens that tab. But i wouldn't know if that is the cause here, because you haven't posted any markup or code. So only mind readers can currently answer your question.

Comment: The `WebView2` is created when the application starts. The code has been added to the problem description.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the visible delay you are wanting to change, I have been struggling with the same thing. Since WebView2 must be used in a UI thread, I don't believe there is a way around that delay yet. For a "this will have to suffice until there is a preload option" solution, I set my DefaultBackgroundColor to the same color as when it is loaded and have a simple "Loading..." label visible until I receive a "Load" message in wv2Editor_WebMessageReceived that I raise with an EventListener in the source html like below:

```
            window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
                window.chrome.webview.postMessage('{ "event":"Load"}');
            });
```